# data blank when i want to update

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code

```
$q_petty = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM `petty` ORDER BY `id` ASC') or die(mysqli_error());
while($row = $q_petty->fetch_array()) {
   echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td> " . date('m/d/Y', strtotime($row['date'])) . "</td>";
      echo "<td> " . number_format((float)$row['cost'], 2, '.', '') . "</td>";
      echo "<td style='text-align: left;'> " . nl2br($row['description']) . "</td>";
      echo "<td>";
         echo "<a href='update-petty-cash.php?id={'id'}' class='btn btn-primary m-r-1em'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit' title='Edit'></span> </a>";
      echo "<a href='#' onclick='delete_petty({'id'});'  class='btn btn-danger'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' title='Delete'></span> </a>";
      echo "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
}
```

When I press edit button to update the data, it doesn't get the data id.
I need help here. before this, it worked fine, after I add search function using date I can't get update the data. The page for update doesn't have the data

Comment: Hard to read a code written like this... Maybe you're looking for `$row["id"]` instead of $id ?. You can also add `$id = $row["id"]` at the first line in your `while` loop so it will work for delete too

Comment: still cant get to it @Zyigh

Comment: Can you show us your code updated please ?

Comment: i have updated the code @ Zyigh

Comment: I don't see an `UPDATE table SET....` so we don't know if the problem's in there (or not).

Comment: So you just didn't listen what the three of us told you to do... also it would have been nice if your code was correctly indented, it is easier to read. on your `<a>` tags, the href should look like `echo "<a href='update-petty-cash.php?id=" . $id . "'" ...`. This way you can easily read your code, and realize that you're not calling any variable

Comment: `mysqli_error()` requires a db connection for it.

Comment: sorry guys, just don't know how to posted in that section with correctly indented. btw, thanx u for helping me :) sorry once again

Answer (score 2):

Break out of the string and concatenate like this:

```
 echo '<a href="update-petty-cash.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" class="btn btn-primary m-r-1em"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" title="Edit"></span> </a>';
```

It's a good idea to use single quotes when dealing with HTML, since HTML frequently uses double quotes.

Comment: Should work now, I forgot to swap a single for double quote in a couple of p[laces

Comment: Same vibe! Use single quotes to encapsulate the string, double quotes for your actual HTML, and break out of the string and concatenate your array value. You can do it! :-D

Answer (score 0):

In the following echo's

```
echo "<a href='update-petty-cash.php?id={$id}' class='btn btn-primary m-r-1em'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit' title='Edit'></span> </a>";
echo "<a href='#' onclick='delete_petty({$id});'  class='btn btn-danger'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' title='Delete'></span> </a>";
```

They both use `$id` which isn't set anywhere, it should probably be `$row['id']` or you can set

```
$id = $row['id'];
```

first.

Comment: Can you give some more information as to what isn't working - does the HTML page have the right ID's in?

Comment: when i click update button, it goes to update page, but with no data in it @Nigel

Comment: Why have you changed the code to have `{'id'}` instead of `{$id}` no wonder it doesn't work.